# Basis functions for a Schauder-Faber-Basis

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I am working through two proofs that there exists a Schauder Basis for $C([0,1])$.

One proof defines a basis $(f_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with
$$
 f_0(x) = 1 \qquad f_1(x) = x
$$
for $2^{k-1} < n \le 2^{k}$, where $k \ge 1$, we define
$$
 f_n(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                    2^k ( x - (2^{-k}(2n - 2) - 1)) & \mathrm{if} ~ x \in I_n \\
                    1 - 2^k ( x - (2^{-k}(2n - 1) - 1)) & \mathrm{if} ~ x \in J_n \\
                    0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
                  \end{array} \right.
$$
where
$$
 I_n = [2^{-k}(2n-2), 2^{-k}(2n-1)) \qquad
 J_n = [2^{-k}(2n-1), 2^{-k}2n).
$$
The graphs of these functions form a sequence of "tents" of height one and width $2^{-k+1}$ that sweep across the interval $[0,1]$.

This proof is from [this notes](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/book/pdfbook.html) page 94.

Another proof I found on the internet goes like this, define the "triangle function"
$$
 \Delta(x) = \begin{cases}
                2x & \mathrm{if } \hspace{2mm} x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right] \\
\\
                2(1-x)  & \mathrm{if } \hspace{2mm} x \in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right] \\
\\
                0 & \mathrm{otherwise}.
             \end{cases}$$
Then consider for $n > 0$
$$
 \Delta_n(x) = \Delta(2^j x - k) \quad \mathrm{for } \qquad n = 2^j + k, \quad j \ge 0,\quad 0 \le k < 2^j
$$
and $\Delta_{-1}(x) = 1, \Delta_0(x) = x$. Then the sequence $\Delta_{-1}, \Delta_0, \Delta_1, \Delta_2, \ldots$ forms a Schauder basis for the Banach space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

I found this proof [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=JuJKu_0KDycC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=triangle%20function%20schauder%20faber&source=bl&ots=m4MbTzFxZN&sig=LywZ_BsCWHhwBIs-xc40qvaq9us&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YkjeT7zYFMvitQbsoezjDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=triangle%20function%20schauder%20faber&f=false) and [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=kH3BxOH6B7kC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=triangle%20function%20schauder%20faber&source=bl&ots=Z-nROsb4Gs&sig=StoLBCm4pyqtc7MVPHFnTMOEdOE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YkjeT7zYFMvitQbsoezjDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=triangle%20function%20schauder%20faber&f=false).
Now here's my question. I tried to prove that both, the $\Delta_n$ and the $f_n$'s, define the same functions, but I am not able to convert the definitions to each other. Do you know how can I proof that these two functions are essentially the same "tent"-functions?

Comment: @Martin Argerami, may be you meant Hamel basis?

Comment: Of course I did. Thanks!

Comment: I am reading the pg 94 of the notes that you provided a link to, and could you explain to me the following?  The author says at the end of the example that the "uniform continuity of f implies that the series converges uniformly. But, why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions $f_n$ specified incorrectly. The correct ones formulas are
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
2^k ( x - (2^{-k}(2n - 2) - 1)) & \text{ if } \quad x \in I_n \\
1 - 2^k ( x - (2^{-k}(2n - 1) - 1)) & \text{ if } \quad x \in J_n \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}.
$$
where 
$$
 I_n = [2^{-k}(2n-2)-1, 2^{-k}(2n-1)-1) \qquad
 J_n = [2^{-k}(2n-1)-1, 2^{-k}2n-1).
$$
In order to prove that $f_n=\Delta_{n-1}$ rewrite these formulas as
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
2^{j+1} ( x - (2^{-j-1}(2n - 2) - 1)) & \text{ if } \quad 2^{-j-1}(2n-2)-1\leq x<2^{-j-1}(2n-1)-1\\
1 - 2^{j+1} ( x - (2^{-j-1}(2n - 1) - 1)) & \text{ if } \quad 2^{-j-1}(2n-1)-1\leq x<2^{-j-1}2n-1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}=
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
2^{j+1} x - n + 1 + 2^{j+1} & \text{ if } \quad (2n-2)\leq 2^{j+1}(x+1)<(2n-1)\\
2n-2^{j+1}x-2^{j+1} & \text{ if } \quad  2n-1\leq 2^{j+1}(x+1)<2n \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}=
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
2(2^{j} x - (n - 1 - 2^{j})) & \text{ if } \quad 0\leq 2^{j} x - (n - 1 - 2^{j})<\frac{1}{2}\\
2-2(2^jx-(n-1-2^j)) & \text{ if } \quad  \frac{1}{2}\leq 2^{j} x - (n - 1 - 2^{j})<1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}=
$$
$$
\Delta(2^jx-(n-1-2^j))=\Delta(2^jx-k)=\Delta_{n-1}(x)
$$
And now we are done.

Comment: There's something wrong in your code for $f_n$, as the functions given in the OP definitely are functions on $[0,1]$ while there's something wiggling over $[1,2]$ in your plots.

Comment: Of course because those functions was incorrect. Now I've written correct formulas.

Comment: I see. Indexing problems. +1 for wading through that horrible mess :)

Comment: @t.b. Thanks! ${}{}{}$